# How to see the nine memory locations being used by assembly directive?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, machine-code, lc3

I am working on a practice problem from  [Lc3 Assembly](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs252/Fall2009/handouts/exam4a_sol.pdf)(Problem 1B)

The Problem: How many memory locations are used by the following assembly directive:

```
.STRINGZ “Football”
```

The answer is 9 which makes sense to me based off from [here](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Winter09/lectures/06_LC3_Assembly.pdf), to have one location store one character.

Here's the Lc3 program I wrote to test this out

```
.ORIG x3000;
LEA R3, YO
HALT
YO .STRINGZ "Football"
.END
```

Here is what I got when the program ran[image]

What happened was address that YO refers to, x3002 was loaded into register 3.

Is there an instruction that I can use to load the (starting)address of the string of characters into R3 instead? I tried ldi but that loaded a negative value...

Comment: That **is** the starting address of your string, not sure what you mean... if you want the length, you could put another label after the string, then subtract the addresses.

Comment: @Jester is there a way of seeing the individual characters, F, o, o, t, b, a, l , l span across x3002, x3002, etc? It looks like those addresses are empty when they should be holding characters.

Comment: Yes, you can see the `F` and the `o` right in your screenshot, at the given addresses. `0x46` is the ascii code of `F`, and `0x6f` is the code for `o`. The disassembler is showing them as `NOP`s but of course they are not instructions so you shouldn't look at that column.

Comment: @Jester Can you take a quick look at these two two real quick? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179866/shouldnt-r3-hold-address-x3307   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179798/what-is-wrong-with-this-line-of-lc3-code   ?

Comment: Please do not use the comments to ask people to look at questions. We will see the questions anyway.