# What is wrong with this line of Lc3 code?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, machine-code, lc3

I am doing a practice exam question.

The Question is

> Is there anything wrong in this line of LC3 code? (The starred line)

```
ADD R3, R3, 0;
**BRNZ ISPOS;**
HALT
.BLKW 250
ISPOS NOT R3, R3 ....
```

I saw that the starred line  is [Branch](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf) and the condition codes are negative and zero, basically go to label ISPOS if the condition code is negative or zero or halt the program otherwise.

I would say that this line of LC3 code has nothing wrong with it. Does anyone see any problems with it?

Comment: Since you only have 9 bits of offset available, that's on the edge of the reachable range, but should barely fit. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Is the assembler case-insensitive for the "nz" flags? Every example I see online has them in lower case as in BRnz.

Comment: @Gene It is case-sensitive only for labels.

Comment: @Gene yeah that caught my eye too but when I assembled the code, there were no errors. So I guess the condition codes are case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a couple different errors with this code segment.

*Opcodes cannot have anything other than a label preceding them.*

```
**BRNZ ISPOS;**
```

**Must become:**

```
BRNZ ISPOS;**
```

*You cannot have any random characters after operands, unless they are commented out*

```
ISPOS NOT R3, R3 ....
```

**Must change to:**

```
ISPOS NOT R3, R3 ;....
```