# Shouldn't R3 hold address x3307?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, machine-code, lc3

I am doing a practice question from [Question 7](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~patt/04f.306/Exams/f04_exam2sol.html)
[image]

Shouldn't the address I highlighted be x3307, not x3308?

The way I reasoned this out was that (PC before 2nd instruction) = (PC after 1st instruction).

The PC after 1st instruction is x3301. Therefore when the second instruction executes, the PC, x3301 will be incremented by 6 to x3307.

Does everyone agree? Or did I miss something and R3 should actually store x3308?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC-relative offsets are applied on top of the already incremented PC, that is the "after" value of the PC, or in other words, the address of the following instruction.

Comment: Ahh I see Fetch increments PC. So it be x3302 when the incrementation performed, storing x3308.

Answer (score 0):

From Appendix A of Patt & Patel, the notational conventions (Table A.1) says this about the PC:

> Program Counter; 16-bit register that contains the memory address of the next instruction to be fetched. For example, during execution of the instruction at address `A`, the PC contains address `A + 1`, indicating the next instruction is contained in `A + 1`.

the specification for the `LEA` opcode says:

> An address is computed by sign-extending bits [8:0] to 16 bits and
>   adding this value to the **incremented** PC.

So when the second instruction is being executed the 'incremented PC' is `0x3302`.  Adding 6 to that results in `0x3308`.